# Sonar not supporting api

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

Im updating a sonar plugin for sonar 3.6 but there is an issue:
This plugin includes workflow class but there is no class such as since api 3.6 
Is there any alternative class or way to do this?

This is the code I work on:

```
package org.sonar.plugins.redmine.reviews;

import org.sonar.api.ServerExtension;
import org.sonar.api.workflow.Workflow;
import static org.sonar.api.workflow.condition.Conditions.*;
import org.sonar.api.workflow.screen.CommentScreen;
import org.sonar.plugins.redmine.RedmineConstants;

public class RedmineWorkflowBuilder implements ServerExtension {

  private final Workflow workflow;
  private final RedmineLinkFunction linkFunction;

  public RedmineWorkflowBuilder(Workflow workflow, RedmineLinkFunction linkFunction) {
    this.workflow = workflow;
    this.linkFunction = linkFunction;
  }

  public void start() {
    workflow.addCommand(RedmineConstants.LINK_TO_REDMINE_ID);
    workflow.setScreen(RedmineConstants.LINK_TO_REDMINE_ID, new CommentScreen());
    workflow.addFunction(RedmineConstants.LINK_TO_REDMINE_ID, linkFunction);
    // conditions for this function
    // - on the review ("IDLE" is the non-persisted status of an non-existing review = when a violation does have a review yet)
    workflow.addCondition(RedmineConstants.LINK_TO_REDMINE_ID, not(hasReviewProperty(RedmineConstants.ISSUE_ID)));
    workflow.addCondition(RedmineConstants.LINK_TO_REDMINE_ID, statuses("IDLE", "OPEN", "REOPENED"));
    // - on the project
    workflow.addCondition(RedmineConstants.LINK_TO_REDMINE_ID, hasProjectProperty(RedmineConstants.HOST));
    workflow.addCondition(RedmineConstants.LINK_TO_REDMINE_ID, hasProjectProperty(RedmineConstants.API_ACCESS_KEY));
    workflow.addCondition(RedmineConstants.LINK_TO_REDMINE_ID, hasProjectProperty(RedmineConstants.PROJECT_KEY));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the SonarQube JIRA plugin - which had the same issue and which have recently been updated to support SonarQube 3.6:

https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-jira

Comment: My problem is keeping on :( How can i get any violation infos(subject,description..) with api?I havent figure out any class for this.